# Loading images from disk with titanium

Tags: webview, titanium, appcelerator

i have some webviews in my app, the webviews loading images from server, I parsed all pathes and cash the images.

So I getting path like this:

file://localhost/Users/Fincha/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/1DC70FE8-0FEA-46AD-9A49-18E78282C2CA/Documents/files/4c06c87edbc3994829483e7b6be1d89c.png

in my iphone simulator, similar on iphone.

I try to replace the pathes in my webview to make the app load images from disk, and it succeed but i cen see no images or even js or stylesheets (they also cached). Image tags rendering empty.

the pathes are the correct, if I create an imageview with the same pathes it works perfectly.

here some code:

```
var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
            // url : urlToShow,
            // image : "file://localhost/Users/Fincha/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/1DC70FE8-0FEA-46AD-9A49-18E78282C2CA/Documents/files/4c06c87edbc3994829483e7b6be1d89c.png",
            html : "<img height='200' width='300' src='file://localhost/Users/Fincha/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.0/Applications/1DC70FE8-0FEA-46AD-9A49-18E78282C2CA/Documents/files/4c06c87edbc3994829483e7b6be1d89c.png' />", // replacePathesInHTML(data.data[elDiD].content),
            height : Titanium.UI.SIZE
        });
```

so how to show images in webview form device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you got this to succeed at all..What is the point of pointing to a file on your computer? If you want to use localhost, setup a local mamp server: http://www.mamp.info and then use a url like `http://localhost/yourimage.png`